# How to create a field in a document while creating another document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model user that has list of badges

```
badges: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'badge'}]
```

And while creating a new badge I want to add this badge to a specific user's list of badges

```
User.findById(id, function(err,user){
      user.badges.push(???)  ///// How to push the badge I'm creating
      user.save(..)
})
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must save badge before pushing into user.badges. Mongodb auto set badge._id property.

```
var badge = new Badge(...);
badge.save().then(badge=>{
    user.badges.push(badge._id);
    user.save;
});
```